# BGE car game problem

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

I have model two car.the first car is okay but the second car is flying when I turn right or left.

[here is the blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50946)

many thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select 370z and hit ctrl+a and aplly scale and do this for its wheels , set wheels to no collision(physics tab). Also set Camera 2  camera object to 370z(logic actuator) if you are making split screen multiplayer game  [image]

Comment: also,i want to make the tire rotate the tire when I turn left or right.but, when I rotate the tire on the axis z, the tire does not rotate

Comment: Add these logic bricks to the wheels (if you want to add them to the other car change A to left arrow and D to right arrow ... you get the point so the rotation does not overlap) .  I edited the main answer see if that is what you wanted. And if you have any more questions ask them.